# How can I put these object data to the mui-datatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mui-datatable

I have these `doses` object from the firestore.

[image]

I can already display all of the data excluding the object `doses`

```
class Users extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [] };
  }

  columns = [
    "Name",
    "Address",
    "Vaccine",
  ];


  componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          console.log("doses", data.doses);
             doc.data().doses.forEach((index) => {
        console.log(index.selectedVaccine);
      });
      
          users.push({
            ...((data.firstName && data.lastName) || data.middleName == " "
              ? {
                  Name:
                    data.firstName +
                    " " +
                    data.middleName +
                    "." +
                    data.lastName,
                }
              : {}),
            Email: data.email,
            Address: data.address,
          });
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
        // console.log(snapshot)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.users ? (
      <MUIDataTable
        title={"List of Users"}
        columns={this.columns}
        data={this.state.users}
        options={this.options}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

When I `console.log("doses", data.doses);` I can view all of the users' `doses` data but I cannot display it in the table. When I tried this part of the code, this would result to "no matching data" inside the mui-datatable:

```
   doc.data().doses.forEach((index) => {
            console.log(index.selectedVaccine);
          });
```

How can I display those doses inside the mui-datatable?

Update: the error is still the same, it says "Sorry, no matching records found" inside the mui-datatable.

```
columns = ["Name", "Email", "Phone Number", "Address", "Vaccine"];

componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          console.log("doses", data.doses);
          users.push({
            ...((data.firstName && data.lastName) || data.middleName == " "
              ? {
                  Name:
                    data.firstName +
                    " " +
                    data.middleName +
                    "." +
                    data.lastName,
                }
              : {}),

            Email: data.email,
            "Phone Number": data.phoneNumber,
            Address: data.address,
            Vaccine: data.doses.selectedVaccine,
          });
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

This is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the columns to the `columns` array for the doses and you can add the data for the doses in the `users` array.

Check out the code samples below:

```js
columns = [
    "Name",
    "Address",
    "Dose 1",
    "Dose 2",
    "First Dose",
    "First Vaccinator",
    "Dose ID"
];
```

```js
users.push({
    ...((data.firstName && data.lastName) || data.middleName == " " ? {
        Name: data.firstName +
            " " +
            data.middleName +
            "." +
            data.lastName,
    } : {}),
    "Address": data.address,
    "Dose 1": data.doses.dose1,
    "Dose 2": data.doses.dose2,
    "First Dose": data.doses.firstDose,
    "First Vaccinator": data.doses.firstVaccinator,
    "Dose ID": data.doses.id
});
```

Also, it looks like you're getting the "no matching data" error because you have "Vaccine" in your `columns` array but you don't have it in your `users` array and you have "Email" in your `users` array but you don't have it in your `columns` array.

Comment: I've updated the post for the new codes and it still has the same error